# Get body content from custom react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

(Sorry if it's a noob question, I just started using React for a week, and didn't find the answer to this question in internet).

I have React component with two properties which is rendering one of this property into text body of `<p>`

```js
function Item({ value, text }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* not relevant code here */}
      <p>{text}</p>
    <div>
  );
}
```

And I'm using it with this code:

```
<Item text="Foo" value="foo"/>
<Item text="Bar" value="bar"/>
<Item text="Baz" value="baz"/>
```

But I want to use it like this:

```js
<Item value="foo">Foo</Item>
<Item value="bar">Bar</Item>
<Item value="baz">Baz</Item>
```

So how can I access the body of React `Item` element and how to pass it to properties?

Comment: props.children should work here. Read more on how react composes components and how you refer to children using props.children

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can destructure [the component children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) from `props`.

```js
function Item({ value, children }) {
  return <div><p>{children}: {value}</p></div>;
}

function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Item value="foo">Foo</Item>
      <Item value="bar">Bar</Item>
      <Item value="baz">Baz</Item>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
p { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 4):

My simple explanation of what props.children does is that it is used to display whatever you include between the opening and closing tags when invoking a component.

change your function component to

```
function Item(props) {
      return (
        <div>
          {props.children}
        <div>
      );
    }
```

Reference : [react's props children](https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891)

Answer (score 4):

@Kirill I hope this will help you .

```
function Item({ value, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* not relevant code here */}
      {children}
    <div>
  );
}
```

Then you can call your Item like this:

```
<Item value="foo">Foo</Item>
<Item value="bar">Bar</Item>
<Item value="baz">Baz</Item>
```

also you can pass other element as children to your **Item** Component also:

```
<Item value="foo">
   <p>Foo</p>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this should work.

```js
function Item({ value, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* not relevant code here */}
      <p>{children}</p>
    <div>
  );
}
```